# How to generate random positions for meshes?

Tags: c++, opengl, mesh

I'm trying to take an OpenGL mesh that I have and give it a random position within a room. I currently have this line of code:

```
positions[i] = glm::vec3(rand() % 10 - 1, rand() % 10 - 1, rand() % 10 - 1);
```

Which just generates a random position (x, y and z). However I'm not entirely sure what the '% 10 - 1' is doing since this code snippet was used online. I can alter the numbers and the mesh moves in the scene but I'm not entirely sure how the numbers are affecting it.

How can I edit the line so that the meshes are not too close together and all fit within the room (I know you don't know the room's dimensions/position, so just an explanation would be very helpful).

Comment: random positions in a mesh arent that different from any other random numbers. You will find tons of questions/answers on that. Try to look for `<random>`, as `rand()` isnt the best rng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part rand() % 10 - 1 : rand() is random number generator. % is modulo operation. So basically rand() % 10 generates all the numbers in the range [0,9]. Now the rand() % 10 - 1 will change the range to [-1,8].

*How can I edit the line so that the meshes are not too close together and all fit within the room (I know you don't know the room's dimensions/position, so just an explanation would be very helpful).*

Simply change 10 to your dimensions max value.

Comment: Perfect, just the explanation I needed, thanks. Is there a good way to ensure that meshes aren't given positions too close to each other? My meshes have collision boxes for physics so I want to avoid overlaps.

Comment: You can use a HashMap or something to store the coordinate. So whenever you got the same coordinate which you have seen already just generate the values again till you get a new coordinate.

Well you cant ensure that meshes aren't given positions because its a random number generator.